# Subclass error: CloneNotSupportedException never being thrown in the try body

Tags: java, inheritance, exception, deep-copy

I'm doing a hand-in right now about inheritance and deep cloning.

The hand-in is about rewriting the code given to us using ideas of inheritance and deep cloning using a program that draws shapes to a canvas.

Right now I've implemented the `clone()` method for both the superclass `point` and my subclass `group`, but I always get a `CloneNotSupportedException` with the `clone()` in my subclass when it compiles and I don't really understand why.

Here's the code for my superclass:

```
public abstract class Point implements Cloneable
{
public Point clone() 
    {
        try {
             Point copy = (Point)super.clone();
             copy.imgGroup = (ArrayList<Point>)imgGroup.clone();
             return copy;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
     }
}
```

Here's the code for my subclass:

```
public class Group extends Point implements Cloneable
{
public Group clone() 
    {
        try {
            Group copy = (Group)super.clone();
            copy.group = (ArrayList<Point>)group.clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
                copy.group.set(i,group.get(i).clone());
            }
            return copy;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }
}
```

The task:

Construct Class `Group`. A certain `Figure` object can be added to several different groups. You have to determine if one and the same `Figure` object can belong to several groups simultaneously or not. In this exercise this should not happen. All `Group` objects must own their item objects exclusively. No sharing of objects between multiple groups may occur.

Therefore, we begin by adding method:

```
public Figure class clone ();
// (define it in the same style as on page 4 in the document below)
// this was what point clone() was in the class Point.
```

After this there were instruction on implementation of some methods and a `Group` clone.

So in this task, i am supposed to implement `Group` with various methods along with a new `clone()`, which is what i am having an issue with right now.

I hope you can help point me in right direction, just wanted to know why this happens. Thanks!

Comment: could you share the homework requirement please?

Comment: it's in swedish so i will try to translate:

Comment: If `Point` is really supposed to be abstract, then just don't implement clone in `Point`, instead let the sub-classes implement `clone()`. With an abstract class you can defer implementation of an inherited interface method to a concrete subclass.

Comment: This might be off topic but is it possible to override the `clone()` declared in `Point` on `Group`?

Comment: Yes. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936164/subclass-error-clonenotsupportedexception-never-being-thrown-in-the-try-body/52943094#52943094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always get a CloneNotSupportedException with the clone() in my subclass

I suppose what you are getting is; `Unreachable catch block for CloneNotSupportedException.`

That is because you have omitted `throws CloneNotSupportedException` from your super class signature. However in the sub class you expect `super.clone()` to throw the checked `CloneNotSupportedException`. Change your super class implementation to;

```
public abstract class Point implements Cloneable {
    public Point clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 
        Point copy = (Point) super.clone(); 
        return copy;
    }
}
```

so that the exception thrown in the super class signature is visible to subclass.

**Update**

Please follow [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936164/subclass-error-clonenotsupportedexception-never-being-thrown-in-the-try-body/52936272?noredirect=1#comment93007043_52936272) below for better clarity.

**Update 2**

Adding more details since the other answer was deleted by the user (where my comment above is referring to).

You cannot instantiate an abstract class - but you still can have a `clone()` method in it. But what's the concrete cloned instance that the abstract class is supposed to return in its clone method? When you say `this` or `super.clone()` in an abstract class, both of these refer to the same subclass instance at run-time. This means the shallow copy (`Point copy = (Point) super.clone();`) is an instance of `Group` in your case. You can add `System.out.println(super.clone().getClass())` in your abstract super class' `clone` method to witness this.

So you can deep clone inheritable attributes in super abstract class - and - deep clone only subclass' attributes in the subclass' clone() method. This way you can avoid deep-cloning super-class attributes in all your subclasses if you have multiple subclasses defined.